# Hooks to run commands after the entire testsuite or at_exit in unittest / pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I need to execute a command after the entire testsuite has run or at the exit of the whole tests. I see `tearDown` hook in **unittest** but there is no after-testsuite hook or something like `at_exit` equivalent in ruby.

Is there any approach in `unittest` or `pytest` which I can follow; or any tweak on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a session-scoped fixture in pytest. As the name implies, it gives you the possibility to run code before and after the entire test session:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def session_setup_teardown():
    # setup code goes here if needed
    yield
    cleanup_testsuite()
```

You best put this fixture into the top-level `conftest.py`.

I'm not aware of a símilar functionality in `unittest` - the closest is probably [`tearDownModule`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule) which is executed once per test module.